# Why this sql query doesn't return any error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When i run these queries:

```
create table University ( branch text primary key, region text, enrollment int);
create table Student ( sID int primary key, sName text, average int);
create table Apply ( sID int references Student(sID), branch text references University(branch), major text, decision text);

insert into Apply values ( 123, 'stanford', 'CS', 'Y');
```

It should return an error because i am inserting a tuple that doesn't have a Corresponding value in the reference table. but when i run these commands, this tuple inersts Successfully. What's wrong with this queries?
My DBMS is sqlite and i'm using sqliteman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn how to [enable foreign key support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)

Quoting docs:

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be
>   compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER
>   defined. If SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER is defined but SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY
>   is not, then SQLite behaves as it did prior to version 3.6.19 -
>   foreign key definitions are parsed and may be queried using PRAGMA
>   foreign_key_list, but foreign key constraints are not enforced. The
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command is a no-op in this configuration. If
>   OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY is defined, then foreign key definitions cannot even
>   be parsed (attempting to specify a foreign key definition is a syntax
>   error).

Also read [sqliteman constraint triggers](http://docs.sqliteman.com/user/en/ch07s08.html):

> There is one more unsupported SQL feature. Sqlite does not enforce
>   foreign keys and not null constraints.